# Does EC2 send logs to CloudWatch by default?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

The metrics which are visible under EC2 monitoring, like network, disk, CPU and status checks, are those sent to CloudWatch? If yes, where are they stored?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the metrics of EC2 instances are stored and monitored by AWS Cloudwatch Metrics service. The default time interval of capturing these metrics is 5 minutes. However, you can enable a close watch upto an interval of 1 minute. This means Cloudwatch metrics can capture the metrics every 1 minute from the EC2 instance and display in the form of graph.

The graphs that you see in the EC2 instance monitoring dashboard are rendered using the Cloudwatch metrics data itself. You can easily view these graphs and several other metrics in the Cloudwatch metrics service.

However, **Logs** from EC2 instances and some other metrics like GPU performance and others are not really sent out to Cloudwatch unless you configure it to. You need to configure a Cloudwatch logs agent for the same. More details are available at this [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/QuickStartEC2Instance.html)

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/as-instance-monitoring.html)

> By default, basic monitoring is enabled when you create a launch template or when you use the AWS Management Console to create a launch configuration. Detailed monitoring is enabled by default when you create a launch configuration using the AWS CLI or an SDK.

The basic basic monitoring sends in 5 minute periods, while the detailed monitoring sends in 1 minute periods.